# Turn off PC and do something before with BASH

Tags: linux, bash, battery

I want to turn off the PC and copy some files before the battery is empty.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOW=11460
BAT=`/bin/cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state | /bin/grep remaining | /usr/bin/awk '{print\$3}'`
if ["$BAT" \< "$LOW"]
then
echo "Turning off"
rsync folder/ otherfolder/
shutdown -h now
fi
```

But its doesn't work!

Comment: which distro you are using?

Comment: im using linuxmint 17.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You are unnecessarily escaping parts of your code and your test expression needs spaces surrounding the variables and a numeric comparison when using the `[` construct. e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOW=11460
BAT=`/bin/cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state | /bin/grep remaining | /usr/bin/awk '{print $3}'`
if [ "$BAT" -lt "$LOW" ]
then
    echo "Turning off"
    rsync folder/ otherfolder/
    shutdown -h now
fi
```

Presuming both `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are in your path, I would make the following changes:

```
BAT=`cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state | grep remaining | awk '{print $3}'`
```

Consider also using `(())` as your test expression. e.g.

```
if ((BAT < LOW))
```

**Note:** spaces surrounding `BAT` and `LOW` are not required when using the `(())` test construct, and there is no need to dereference your variable with `$` inside `(())` unless using brace expansion or array syntax. e.g. `((${#array[@]} < something))`.

Additionally, since you are calling a script that requires `root` privileges to call `shutdown`, you should test for `root EUID` at the beginning:

```
if ((EUID != 0)); then
    printf "error: script must be run by root, EUID: '%s' can't.\n" $EUID
    exit 0
fi
```

or if you prefer the normal `[` test construct:

```
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
...
```